# How to properly embed form served by Orbeon Forms in HTML document?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm new to orbeon Forms and I have trouble to embed form into my PHP application.

I have virtual machine with ubuntu-server 16.04 with installed:

1. NGINX + PHP application on https://localhost/
2. Tomcat8 + Orbeon Forms 2016.3 CE serving simple form on https://localhost:8443/orbeon/testapp/form

Now I want to embed my form into my site so in my index.php I do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My form:</h1>
        <?php
            $arrContextOptions=array(
                "ssl"=>array(
                    "verify_peer"=>false,
                    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
            );
            echo file_get_contents('https://localhost:8443/orbeon/testapp/form?orbeon-embeddable=true', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
            foreach ($http_response_header as $header){
                $groups = [];
                if (preg_match('/Set\-Cookie: JSESSIONID=(.*?);/i', $header, $groups)){
                    setcookie('JSESSIONID', $groups[1], 0, '/orbeon/', '', true, true);
                    break;
                }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this shows me broken form. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding is much more difficult than that, unfortunately. There is an old document, [Embedding and Proxying Orbeon Forms](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/proxying-orbeon-forms), which covers some of the things to do.

Orbeon Forms puts this in practice in the [Java embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api.html), which is implemented in Scala [here as of 2017-05](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/ff0bbf1868dc0508bf6f288de7c25eaa40a39187/embedding/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fr/embedding).

There is also an outdated [TYPO3 extension](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/orbeon) which you could download for inspiration, as it is implemented in PHP.